# Can I use the Dashboard the WSO2 DAS from other aplication java

Tags: java, wso2, dashboard, complex-event-processing

I have a Dashboard that diagram information from Stream. I want use this Dashboard in other java aplication.

There are antecedents?, is it possible ?

thank you for your comments.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your requirement. It is not directly possible to embed the dashboard to a third party application in current releases. However, you can use the DAS dashboard URL and add an iframe in your application to refer the dashboard from your application. (For this you should have the DAS server up and running.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not directly possible to embed the dashboard to a third party application in current releases. However, you can use the DAS dashboard URL and add an iframe in your application to refer the dashboard from your application. (For this you should have the DAS server up and running.

Comment: But, how is the best way for manage the authentication and the time out ?